# Remove duplicate lines in file that doesn't appear in sequence

Tags: linux, bash

The `uniq` tool isn't a good fit because it only works on duplicate lines that appear right after the previous ones i.e. in sequence.

Instead, I want something that turns a textfile `dupl.txt`. Also, I don't need to preserve ordering.

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
```

into

```
aaa
bbb
```

or

```
bbb
aaa
```

Comment: `sort | uniq` will do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `sort` the output before using `uniq`, it will work as desired.

For example, I use the following kind of command all the time:

```
cat access.log | grep "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` only:

```
sort -u dupl.txt > uniq.txt
```

`-u` switch has the same effect like:

```
sort dupl.txt | uniq > uniq.txt
```